# Touch events on code blocks are displaced by scroll-top

Tags: bug, android-app

I was navigating [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/copy-a-specific-percentage-of-each-file-in-a-directory-to-a-new-file) (the circle is my finger, courtesy of Developer Options):

1. Vertical scrolling works fine for the question and answers
2. Horizontal scrolling works fine at first while I'm on the top of a long question / answer
3. As I go down the amount I have to touch higher is proportional to how much is not visible from the top of the question/answer
4. Towards the end it's really a lot, it takes a few seconds just to find the right spot :)
5. But opening the code blocks works just fine with a tap

[image: Demonstration of the bug]

I would expect 3 and 4 to work fine as 5 hits the targeted view.

---

Tried Samsung Galaxy S3 @ 4.3 and Nexus 7 2012 @ 5.1.1 with 1.0.77 (those accounts are not in beta group) and it doesn't repro there.

I was able to reproduce it only on my Samsung Galaxy S4 @ 4.4.2 with 1.0.82 beta (and whatever version I had at the end of 2014). I tried disabling Developer Options to check for interference, but nothing has changed.

---

It may or may not help to look into [`setOnTouchListener -> view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121491/is-it-possible-to-add-a-scrollable-textview-to-a-listview).

*I originally reported this bug via `androidapp@stackexchange.com` on 2014-12-06, but no response.*

Comment: Uh, your link is dead, making it hard to see how the bug in action again... but probably it's fixed/not repro'd on latest version (1.0.77/1.0.82beta).

Comment: @AndrewT. created a new one. This demo is with 1.0.82 beta. Sorry about the lagging, I had to do it at 5 FPS to be able to upload it (2M limit).

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1. Mind also providing the device model and Android version?

Comment: Updated question with version and repro info.

Comment: @qwer Present even today with the latest version. Can't reproduce when typing a question manually (or maybe it works when typing a question), but for longer q/a with more than 3-4 blocks it appears. I first thought it depended on the in-line code block(backticks), but now it doesn't seem so. Stock Android 4.4.2, Galaxy Note 2.